# How to add a wait timer on an input field keyup event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, user-input

I have an input field, and it has a keyup event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#SearchInputBox').keyup(function() {
        DoSearch($(this).val());
    });
});
```

How can I add a delay time, so that only when the user stopped typing for 1 second, then it will run the DoSearch function. I don't want to keep running it every time the user types a key because if they type fast, then it will lag.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basically, set a timeout on each keyup. If there's already a timeout running, clear it and set another. The `DoSearch()` function will only run when the timeout is allowed to complete without being reset by another keyup (i.e., when the user has stopped typing for 1000ms).

```
var timeout = null;
$('#SearchInputBox').on('keyup', function () {
    var that = this;
    if (timeout !== null) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        DoSearch($(that).val());
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: @omega, apologies, I was focused on firing the event after the timeout that I didn't pay attention to the value you were passing.  Of course `$(this)` didn't work, because it is in a different function scope. Please see my current edit. Thanks.